# How do I communicate between a rotary and stationary part? (on a hobbyist level)

Tags: pcb, components, design, rotary, hid

I'm trying to get into PCB design and I'm very new to all of this. I tried doing some research myself but couldn't find anything practical as it'd be too large/expensive. The thing I'm trying to make is a human interface device and I want to have a PCB rotate (like full 360* in either direction) on a circular platform, and then have it communicate the data from buttons on that PCB to a micro controller on a stationary PCB elsewhere. I don't want to use a wireless connection because response time is important for what i'm trying to do. Additionally, since its an HID the part cant be big and needs to be pretty flat/small; What would be a practical way of doing this?

[image: MSpaint model]

Comment: How fast does it need to be? how small? how is the turning pcb supported? what other approaches have you rejected, and why?

Comment: what's on the moving part?

Comment: Simplest is spring on one part touched to the slider on other part. Other options are optic, electromagnetic or rf.

Comment: If you tell us what it is, maybe we can suggest a completely different approach, one that does not require a rotating connection.

Comment: If it only needs to rotate 360° and no further, you can just use wires that have sufficient slack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Freely rotating part that conducts electricity to fixed part - does this exist?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666917/freely-rotating-part-that-conducts-electricity-to-fixed-part-does-this-exist)

Comment: *I don't want to use a wireless connection* <-- you must either use wires or use wireless.  But if you are ruling out wireless, you are ruling out the only possibility of success.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution to pass power and data across a rotating joint- a rotary transformer.

[image]

It consists of two concentric coils with an annular ferrite core (from a POV LED display kit designed in China).

Answer (score 2):

The standard solution is a [slip ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring).

But a reliable slip ring is expensive.

If reliability is not a requirement, you can find a cheap 2-circuit slip ring in a [hair curler](https://guide-images.cdn.ifixit.com/igi/5hMKh6SWXigSChxp.full). [Source](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Conair+Infiniti+PRO+Curling+Iron+Power+Cord+Replacement/100602)

In my experience, quite often the best solution is to rotate something other than electrical connections. For example, if you want to rotate an LED, the best solution is to keep the LED stationary and rotate a 45 degree mirror.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers suggesting slip rings (the phono jack suggestion basically is just suggesting a slip ring, just using something not designed as a slip ring as one):

You say you only need 360° rotation in either direction (i.e. that you don't need it to spin any further than one full rotation from the center position). If that's actually what you mean, and you don't actually mean you need free rotation, you can just use a wire loom with sufficient slack. If this will rotate frequently, use wire designed to be flexed frequently. Machine tool wire is specifically designed for that--that's the wire they use to connect things in robotic assembly equipment that's basically always moving.

If you *do* actually mean you need free rotation (i.e. you can spin it well beyond 360°), then you need either slip rings or something wireless. If you don't consider it "wireless", you can use a transformer to couple power and data across. If the PCBs are close enough, you can use planar coils on each one, potentially with some molded ferrite to act as a transformer core. This method doesn't introduce any significant delay (which is why you say you don't want to do anything wireless, but I'm assuming by "wireless" you're thinking of protocols like bluetooth or zigbee that have some protocol overhead), so it should be perfectly suitable. The only difficulty is in modulating the data on top of the power, if this needs to transfer power as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two TS phone plugs/sockets as axis and contact.  Professional solutions can be found by a web search for "rotating electrical connector".  Best connectivity tends to be done with mercury contacts.  Pretty good contacts for power transmission are provided by slip rings.  You could try finding a defective car alternator and disassemble it for parts.  Data transmission may end up sort of noisy using slip rings (or the phone plug solution): you probably need low transfer rates and RC elements for lowpass filtering.

Answer (score 0):

If the board is on some form of turntable with no obstructions, you could suspend wire(s) from a point above it and the board could turn freely through 360 degrees, maybe more. The restriction is how many twists the wiring harness can take. You might need a lot of strain relief.

Without more context it is not possible to say whether this is a workable solution or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some flashlights have solved this problem by various means, since the head of the flashlight usually has to turn (or the tail). You may be able to leverage some of their designs, and even parts. Some you can even open in the store, like  this [Lantern flashlight at Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rayovac-Brite-Essentials-4-LED-Floating-Lantern-6V-Battery-Included-200-Lumens/22086119).

[image]

Here are some pictures of what's inside.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]